# How do I make Command+Tab only bring the active window for an application to the foreground?

Tags: macos, mission-control

When I switch to an application using <kbd>⌘ + tab</kbd>, *all* the open windows for that application are brought forward (usually covering other windows in other apps that I want to see). I would like only the active/selected window for that application brought forward. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I would be happy to change this globally, as the existing behavior drives me batty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple's solution, like it or not, is to use Exposé or [Mission Control](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/20/mac-os-x-lion-and-mission-control/) (Lion) to switch between windows. <kbd>⌘ + tab</kbd> is considered an application switcher.

There are third party solutions to change this behavior, but I don't have experience with them. There is some discussion about these solutions on [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/193922).

Comment: Well, this nails it (sigh). I wish Mission Control were easier to navigate quickly (<= 2 keystrokes). Thanks for the pointers to the third party options; I'll check them out.